# Angular UI Router not rendering nested views and links

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been learning Angular and now that I have a while learning it I decide to make an small app to test my knowledge, but the links on my app and the nested views doesn't seem to work for a reason I can't understand yet, I've using angular-ui-router because it's pretty awesome to handle routes and that sort of things.

**the problem:** I'm trying to load the templates of the routes into the div that contains the ui-view but it doesn't work.

I have this three js files:

first **config.route.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('weekobApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

        // route for the home page
        .state('app', {
            url:'/',
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl : 'app/layout/header.html',
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl : 'app/layout/dashboard.html',
                    controller  : 'DashboardController'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl : 'app/layout/footer.html',
                }
            }

        });
});
```

**dashboard.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('weekobApp', [])
    .controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myname = "Dashboard";
}]);
```

and finally the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="weekobApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- build:css content/styles/style.css -->
    <link href="content/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>

    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>

    <!-- build:js app/main.js -->
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Dashboard modules -->
    <script src="app/dashboard/config.route.js"></script>
    <script src="app/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should only declare the module dependency list once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only declare the module dependency list once:

```
angular.module('weekobApp', ['ui.router']);

angular.module('weekobApp')
     .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

angular.module('weekobApp')
     .controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

The first line creates the module. The other two add components to the module. Your code was overwriting the previous component.

Comment: I did this but now I'm getting this problem "[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module weekobApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr]" and it's still not showing any template by the way!

Comment: Show more of the error message. What is the name of the provider in the error message?

Comment: this is the error I'm getting https://goo.gl/Kze4xL , when I add a parameter [] to the angular.module inside the dashboard.js this error dissapear, I know it's because it overwrites the dependencies, but I'm just saying.

Comment: Works fine in [this PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/QLS8hQJYSHUBOxtw6Jhb?p=preview).

Comment: The error was related with this and the minified files, somhow it was causing problems.